# Cache busting mechanism for Java/SpringMVC/Maven project

Tags: javascript, css, maven, caching, browser

A little background about the app that I'm working in: Spring MVC, Java EE Web application, Maven.

Basically, what I'm looking for is a mechanism to refresh all JS and CSS files upon each deployment of our application. As it stands right now, the application is referencing static files (e.g. "js/app.js"). Every time there is a change to this file, after redeploying locally, we get a 304 when the browser goes to download it (file has not been modified). My questions are:

1) Would it be better to serve these files up again upon redeployment of application and use maybe the application version as a cache busting mechanism (e.g. "js/v1.0.0/app.js").  This can maybe be done via a servlet filter.

2) Since the project is a maven dynamic web project, is there some sort of plugin that does this sort of thing.  I was looking at wro4j to see if it can do this, but from the very little I read about it, it's mostly used to handle minification of these JS and CSS, which is something also very useful.

Which is the right approach? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you use a query string as in common practice for CMS' such as Drupal? Example URL: path/to/file.js?123456 Example URL after next deploy: path/to/file.js?123456?[UNIX TIMESTAMP/RANDOM STRING/SOME VAR]

Comment: Have this same requirement right now. What did you do in the end @Kruiz

Comment: I've been using a Microsoft stack for a long time. I'm interested in finding out best practices for bundling, minification, and cache busting now that I'm working with a Java, Spring, and Tomcat stack.

I understand this is an old post, but can you share your findings?

Thanks!
-V

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the "right" approach but the most common solution is to use versioning of the static files e.g app.js will become app-14gd54646rfw3.js the number is usually a MD5 of the content thus it will only change when the file changes

with spring you achieve it by built-in mechanism as described at the following link
http://www.baeldung.com/cachable-static-assets-with-spring-mvc

if you want to use Maven plugin with concatenating and minifying abilities you can use a gulp or grunt tasks as build tools

you can find more information here 
https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/

Answer (score -3):

you should add versions to your static resources or disable caching in browser

Comment: Disabling cache is not really user friendly.